# Using createContext to share API data globally through React app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-context

I'm currently working on an app that fetches data from an API and displays it on the front-end. I've got the data coming up correctly when I print it to the console (so I know fetching the data isn't an issue) and I want to be able to use this data globally across different components. I'm aiming to use `createContext` to do this but haven't figured it out yet. Here's my code so far:

**useFetch.ts**

```
export const useFetch = (url: string) => {
    const [fetchedData, setFetchedData] = useState(null);
    const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        getAllFetchedData()
    }, []);

    const getAllFetchedData = async () => {
        await axios.get(url).then((response) => {
            const data = response.data;
            setFetchedData(data)
            setLoaded(true)
        })
            .catch(error => console.error(`Error: ${error}`));
    }

    return [loaded, fetchedData];
}
```

**DataProvider.tsx**

```
type PostProviderProps = {
    children: React.ReactNode
}

export default function DataProvider({ children }: PostProviderProps) {
    const [loaded, data] = useFetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`)
    return (
        <PostContext.Provider value = {[loaded, data]}>
            {children}
        </PostContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

**DataContext.ts**

```
type PostContextType = {
    userId: number;
    id: number;
    title: string;
    body: string;
}

const PostContext = createContext<PostContextType>({} as PostContextType)
export default PostContext
```

If anybody could help it'd be really appreciated

Comment: What is the issue? What do you need help with?

Comment: The type of the context and the value you pass in do not seem to align

Comment: @DrewReese: My issue is just trying to figure out how to use the data globally. I don't want to call the data each time I make a new component. I've read that createContext can manage a state globally so I thought about using it but I'm not too sure how it works out. Fairly new to React and Typescript so can't say I have the best understanding just yet :)

Comment: So you just need to consume the `PostContext` in a child component somewhere?

Comment: Oh, I think I see an issue. The `PostContext` is typed to be an object with `userId`, `id`, `title`, and `body` properties, but the value you are trying to provide is an array of the `loaded` and `data` values returned from the `useFetch` hook. What are you really wanting to provide to the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PostContext` is typed to be an object with `userId`, `id`, `title`, and `body` properties, but the value you are trying to provide is an array of the `loaded` and `data` values returned from the `useFetch` hook. It appears that you are fetching an array of posts.

I suggest the following updates to the code.

First, update the `useFetch` hook to take a generic type for the fetched return value.

```
const useFetch = <T extends unknown>(url: string): [boolean, T | null] => {
  const [fetchedData, setFetchedData] = useState<T | null>(null);
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getAllFetchedData = async () => {
      await axios
        .get(url)
        .then((response) => {
          const data = response.data;
          setFetchedData(data);
          setLoaded(true);
        })
        .catch((error) => console.error(`Error: ${error}`));
    };

    getAllFetchedData();
  }, []);

  return [loaded, fetchedData];
};
```

Update the context to use a better interface that aligns with (1) what you are fetching and (2) what you want to provide to the app as a context value.

```
interface Post {
  userId: number;
  id: number;
  title: string;
  body: string;
}

interface PostContextType {
  loaded: boolean;
  posts: Post[] | null;
}

const PostContext = createContext<PostContextType>({
  loaded: false,
  posts: []
});
```

Create the `DataProvider` component and a custom hook to access the context.

```
const usePosts = () => React.useContext(PostContext);

function DataProvider({ children }: React.PropsWithChildren<{}>) {
  const [loaded, data] = useFetch<Post[]>(
    `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`
  );

  const value = {
    loaded,
    posts: data
  };

  return (
    <PostContext.Provider value={value}>
      {children}
    </PostContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Wrap the app code with the provider.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <DataProvider>
      ....
    </DataProvider>
  );
}
```

Consume the context in a descendent component.

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const { loaded, posts } = usePosts();

  return loaded ? (
    posts?.map((post) => (
      <div key={post.id}>
        <h2>{post.title}</h2>
        <h3>{post.userId}</h3>
        <p>{post.body}</p>
      </div>
    ))
  ) : (
    <>"Loading"</>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit using-createcontext-to-share-api-data-globally-through-react-app]

Comment: You're a legend, this was exactly what I needed and it works perfectly! Thank you so much! :D

Comment: This is a well written answer.  Is this all written as a single file?  I want to fully understand this, and am slightly unsure If I do.  Does the `const usePosts` declaration _belong_ in that block, or would it equally well go in the one above? I'd expect it would have to be exported if each block represents a file, am I right?  How would I update the context within the application?

Comment: Of course, I answered my own first question, also likely the second, when I clicked the sandbox button.

Comment: @VeteranCoder I declared everything in a single file in the sandbox, which is completely valid, but I'm a lazy programmer so I didn't break everything down in the sandbox. Typically you'd declare the Context and its related parts in its own file, the Context, interfaces, Provider, any custom hooks, etc... and import the constituent parts where necessary. Same with the `useFetch` hook and other standalone hooks.